# Guid vs. integer ID for unique fields

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, uuid

This is really a generic question.

Suppose I have a replication pattern of a single write DB and multiple read DB replication slaves - I do not have to have GUID's as my unique IDs fields. Is that a correct assumption?

If I have multiple DB instances where all are writeable and sync between themselves, GUID's in unique ID fields is mandatory. Is that also correct?

I am setting up PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS.

Thanks.

Comment: To have Postgres generate UUID values, you'll need the OSSP UUID extension. Search StackOverflow for instructions. This extension *is* available in Amazon RDS Postgres, but you must activate it with a call to `CREATE EXTENSION`.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I have a replication pattern of a single write DB and multiple
>   read DB replication slaves - I do not have to have GUID's as my unique
>   IDs fields. Is that a correct assumption?

Correct. As Basil Bourque wrote it doesn't matter what you kind of IDs you use if you have a single master source of data.

> If I have multiple DB instances where all are writeable and sync
>   between themselves, GUID's in unique ID fields is mandatory. Is that
>   also correct?

No, it is not mandatory to use GUID in this case, but it may be convenient.

I assume a quite common scenario: You have `N` writable databases DB1 - DBn. They can "talk" to each other to exchange data, but connection between them is not 24/7 or not fast enough to be done "in real-time" as the data changes. So, each database accumulates its changes locally and then periodically the changes are transferred to other databases. Since, once in a while all databases have exactly same data, there must be a method to assign some identifier to each row that would be unique not just within one database, but within all databases.

There are many ways to achieve it, GUID is just one.
Another common method is to have ID that consists of two parts: ID of the database plus standard sequence of growing unique numbers.

Another method that I used for two-way sync of two databases: ID effectively consists of two numbers. First number is a standard unique sequence of the local database, second number is a sequence from remote database.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, "replication" means an exact copy. So the data type of your ID (primary key) columns is irrelevant. Whatever data is written into the master database gets written into the replicants be it integers, UUIDs, or text. Think "Xerox copies of each invoice as written", not "writing new fresh separate invoices".

If you are exchanging data between systems, or [federating](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_database_system) multiple database systems, then your primary key becomes a critical issue.

Sequential numbers are tricky to coordinate across multiple sources of data. One option for coordinating is to assign a range of numbers to be used by each source. The Montréal office uses numbers under one billion, and the Paris office uses numbers starting at one billion. Such schemes have proved clumsy or failures in my experience.

UUIDs were invented for such purposes because they require no coordination between sources of data.  The original Version 1 UUIDs eliminate any practical chance of collisions. Even the entirely-random UUIDs will have no collisions for any limited number of records if generated with a quality random generator.

Comment: Then perhaps my terminology is flawed. If you have multiple WRITE databases that need to be synched between themselves using UUID is recommended so that new records don't get the same unique ID - correct? Is "Syncing" multiple write/read databases different than "replication"? is replication always one-directional master->slave(s) ?

Comment: I assume by "replication" you mean the [streaming replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication) feature built into Postgres 9.x. The basic idea is simple: Any data going into the database also goes into a log file, and replication means shipping a copy of that log file to a duplicate of your database to be incorporated in parallel to the master DB. So IDs are irrelevant. No comparisons between the two databases, no business logic.

Comment: As for "syncing", I don't know specifically what you mean. Usually the term means two or more sources of data that also act as sinks for each other. So all the sources/sinks must carry on a conversation comparing what changes have occurred independent of the other, then communicating the content of those changes to each. By definition, this is inherently tricky and problematic. And, the IDs are crucial. If your architecture requires that the systems be able to work independently, then the IDs should be immutable and able to be generated independently. That is the purpose of UUIDs.

Comment: Sounds like you need to get clear on what *you* mean by "replicating" and "syncing". Don't let the technology details confuse you. Imagine replacing the systems with remote offices, clerks, paper, file cabinets, Xerox and fax machines, and telephones. All the issues are the same, as are the solutions. No magic added by computers, just speed.

Comment: how do people scale databases? If there is more than one write-database It needs some kind of syncing. I was asking how ID's are handled in this case.